# How to track an object inside an ArrayList becoming null?

Tags: java, arraylist

The structure that I have is:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Bean>>
```

This Arraylist is modified (added/removed) from different locations within different threads.

At times, some bean inside the `ArrayList` is becoming `null`. How can I track when it becomes null? I want to track what makes the bean null, to fix the bug.

This happens when the scenario is tested with a huge data set.

Here's the exact code that's failing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eventlogs.size(); i++) {
    MessageEventLogBean msgEventLogBean = (MessageEventLogBean) eventlogs.get(i);
    eventlogs.remove(i); 
    try {
        logWriter.write(msgEventLogBean, context);
    } catch (FusionException e) {
        logger.error("Error While writing the event log bean ", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @I suspect this is a java question?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Arraylist itself. But Do you have access to the code of the object that is referenced by it? If yes, you could add some code in the finalize-Method so perform some action when the object is being destroyed.

Comment: @Compuholic: Thanks Compuholic

Comment: @Compuholic It might give you a clue, but remember that the finalize method is not guaranteed to be called in a timely fashion, and is called from a different thread to the garbage colletor (via an asynchronous queue), and thus the *reason* for the object losing all references (and thus garbage collected) is long gone and all traces (eg stacktrace etc) to find the culprit are unavailable

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a standard list implementation, use an anonymous class that overrides the `add` method and adds special code to check if the added object is null, like this:

```
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>() {
        public boolean add(T e) {
            if (e == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Attempt to add null to list");
            }
            return super.add(e);
        }
    };
```

You should similarly override all "add" methods to be sure. When code adds a null, it will explode and you will see the exception in the log and be able to see who did it be examining the stacktrace.

#### EDITED

To be clear, it is **impossible** for an object in a List to "become `null`". You can *add* a `null`, or you can *remove* an object from the List, but an object *already in* the List will stay there until removed.

To be clear, the **only** way for a `null` to get in the list is by putting it there - ie adding it via one of the `add()` methods or the `addAll()` method. Concurrent modification issues can **not** cause this issue (you may get a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), but that still won't put a `null` in there).

Code such as

```
Object o = list.get(1);
o = null;
```

has no effect because you're just nulling a *copy* of the reference to the object - `list` still a reference to the object.

However, depending on the design of the `Bean` objects, they might be mutable. While the reference to the Bean object would remain intact, it might be possible for some of the fields *within* the Bean to become `null`. To catch this, you would need to code the setters to explode when given a `null` argument, either by re-writing the class, or by overloading the setters via an anonymous class (similar to my initial suggestion above).

Comment: My question was different. This is useful only while adding an element and not in context with tracking the reference going null inside the collection.

Comment: @Narita Please read the edited section in my answer that hopefully addresses your need

Comment: @Bohemian: You are correct. I did run a simple code and found that even though we assign null to the reference, the actual object inside the list remains un modified. Like - `temp = list.get(1); temp = null;` this has no effect on the object at `list.get(1);`. 1) Can you help me understanding why is it so?

Comment: I did see the object inside the list as null while debugging. Can this be due to concurrent modification?

Comment: @Bohemian and @Peter Lawrey : `for (int i = 0; i < eventlogs.size(); i++) { MessageEventLogBean msgEventLogBean = (MessageEventLogBean) eventlogs.get(i); eventlogs.remove(i); try { logWriter.write(msgEventLogBean, context); } catch (FusionException e) { logger.error("Error While writing the event log bean ", e); } }` msgEventLogBean is null during the get(). This code is getting accessed by multiple threads. Can this be due to concurrent modification? I understand the remove() inside the loop is pathetic.

Comment: @Bohemian: Thanks. I will try catch the null while adding elements to the list. I should be getting the dataset by weekend and update you on this. This error is occured only with a huge data set.

Comment: It looks like you should be using a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), which is built to do exactly this function - a producer/consumer pattern

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of work, but you can create your own List interface implementation that delegates all methods to the ArrayList. In the accessor method where you would normally return the ArrayList, instead return your debug implementation with the ArrayList wrapped inside of it. Then just set a breakpoint on your set method, and you'll know exactly what code is calling set on the ArrayList.

Comment: My question was different. This is useful only while adding an element and not in context with tracking the reference going null inside the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you intended

```
private final Queue<MessageEventLogBean> eventlogs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

// this loop stops when it runs out of objects.
MessageEventLogBean msgEventLogBean;
while ((msgEventLogBean = eventlogs.poll()) != null) {
    try {
        logWriter.write(msgEventLogBean, context);
    } catch (FusionException e) {
        logger.error("Error While writing the event log bean ", e);
    }
}
```

or

```
// this loops until the thread is interrupted
private final BlockingQueue<MessageEventLogBean> eventlogs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

while (true) {
    MessageEventLogBean msgEventLogBean = eventlogs.take();
    try {
        logWriter.write(msgEventLogBean, context);
    } catch (FusionException e) {
        logger.error("Error While writing the event log bean ", e);
    }
}
```

Both options are thread safe.

---

You can override the add() and set() methods for the list so that `null` is invalid and throws an exception.

```
List<MyType> list = new ArrayList<MyType>() {
    public boolean add(MyType mt) {
        if(mt == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        super.add(mt);
    }
};
```

---

Consider the following code

```
String a = "hi"; // a => "hi"
String b = a; // a => "hi" and b => "hi"
a = null; // a => null and b => "hi"
```

`String a` is a reference to a String and when you assign `null` to it you change just the value of `a` and other references to the same object are unaffected.

---

A way to process every second entry, or why using remove(i) is unlikely to be what you want.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) list.add(i);
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
    list.remove(i);
}
```

prints

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: My question was different. This is useful only while adding an element and not in context with tracking the reference going null inside the collection.

Comment: The reference won't go `null` automatically.  A method has to be called to set it to null.

Comment: `List<MyType> list = new ArrayList<MyType>() { public boolean add(MyType mt) { if(mt == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); super.add(mt); } }; list.add(new MyType()); list.add(new MyType()); list.add(new MyType()); // Assume that get returns the reference and not a clone. list.get(1) = null;` In my case, the last step in happening within a different thread which I am unable to track due to huge data and presence of lot of threads. I want to know how can I track the reference becoming null.

Comment: get(1) return the reference to the object, but not a reference to the reference. `list.get(1) = null;` doesn't compile so you don't have to worry about this one. ;)

Comment: Can you give me any clue? Refer my latest comment for Bohemian.

Comment: It appears you are access a list in a way which is not thread safe when what you want is a queue. BTW: if you remove(i) you will see every second entry. I doubt this is intended.